# Is there a 6 second delay setting in spyder compiling an empty script?

Tags: python, time, editor, development-environment, spyder

I just noticed today that when I compile a script in spyder, after the console returns >>>, I would click on the editor, and it would freeze for a few seconds. I visually clocked compiling an empty script, immediately returning >>>, and it took 6 seconds for the editor to unlock itself for me to click and edit the text in the editor.

Is there a 6 second delay setting in spyder compiling an empty script?

Comment: I highly doubt there is a "setting" that causes it .. *but* it might very well 'momentarily hang' based on what is happening.

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) This sounds like a bug. Please open an issue in our [issue tracker](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues) and post there the script that's causing your error.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba I will do more testing. I think its because the script is located on my usb?